# How to protect against tampering with the URL in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My Rails  student planner application has a few issues regarding URL tampering. I believe they probably all share a similar solution but I'm having difficulty.

When viewing an assignment (`students/:id/assignments/:id`), changing the assignment’s ID in the URL to the ID of an assignment belonging to another student sometimes leads to a "no method error" in my `assignments#show` page, other times it will show the other student's assignment, when ideally I'd like to just redirect  back to their home page.

Similarly, this happens with the assignment's edit page (`students/:id/assignments/:id/edit`), course (`students/:id/courses/:id`) and course's edit page (`students/:id/courses/:id/edit`). Sometimes I'll get an "ArgumentError in `Assignments#edit`" when viewing an assignment's edit page.

I believe these should be able to be remedied in my controllers, so  I've included my `assignments_controller` and `courses_controller`.

Assignments_controller:

```
class AssignmentsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_logged_in
  before_action :set_student

  def new
    if @student && @student.id == current_student.id
      @assignment = Assignment.new
      @courses = Course.where(student_id: current_student.id)
    else
      redirect_to student_path(current_student), error: 'Sorry, you can\'t view another Users assignments.'
    end
  end

  def create
    @assignment = Assignment.new(assignment_params)
    @assignment.student_id = current_student.id if current_student
    @courses = Course.where(student_id: current_student.id)

    if @assignment.save
      redirect_to student_assignments_path(@student)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def index
    if @student && @student.id == current_student.id
      @assignments = Assignment.where(student_id: current_student.id)
    else
      redirect_to student_path(current_student), error: 'Sorry, you can\'t view another Users assignments.'
    end
  end

  def show
    #student = Student.find_by(id: params[:student_id])
    if @student && @student.id == current_student.id
      #@assignment = student.assignments.find_by(id: params[:id])
      @assignment = Assignment.find_by(id: params[:id])
    else
      redirect_to student_path(current_student), error: 'Sorry, you can\'t view another Users assignments.'
    end
  end

  def edit
    if @student && @student.id == current_student.id
      @assignment = Assignment.find_by(id: params[:id])
    else
      redirect_to student_path(current_student), error: 'Sorry, you can\'t view another Users assignments.'
    end
  end

  def update
    student = Student.find_by(id: params[:student_id])
    @assignment = Assignment.find_by(id: params[:id])
    @assignment.update(params.require(:assignment).permit(:title, :due_date))
    redirect_to student_assignment_path(student, @assignment)
  end

  def destroy
    @student = Student.find_by(id: params[:student_id])
    @assignment = Assignment.find_by(id: params[:id]).destroy
    redirect_to student_path(@student), notice: 'Assignment was successfully completed.'
  end

  private

    def assignment_params
      params.require(:assignment).permit(:title, :due_date, :course_id, :student_id)
    end

    def set_student
      @student = Student.find_by(id: params[:student_id])
    end
end
```

Courses_controller:

```
class CoursesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_logged_in
  before_action :set_student

  def new
    if @student && @student.id == current_student.id
      @course = Course.new
    else
      redirect_to student_path(current_student), error: 'Sorry, you can\'t view another Users courses.'
    end
  end

  def create
    if @student && @student.id == current_student.id
      @course = Course.create(course_params)
      @course.student_id = params[:student_id]

      if @course.save
        redirect_to student_courses_path(@student)
      else
        render :new
      end
    else
      redirect_to student_path(current_student), error: 'Sorry, you can\'t view another Users courses.'
    end
  end

  def index
    if @student && @student.id == current_student.id
      @courses = Course.where(student_id: current_student.id)
    else
      redirect_to student_path(current_student), error: 'Sorry, you can\'t view another Users courses.'
    end
  end

  def show
    @student = Student.find_by(id: params[:student_id])
    if @student && @student.id == current_student.id
      @course = @student.courses.find_by(id: params[:id])
    else
      redirect_to student_path(current_student), error: 'Sorry, you can\'t view another Users courses.'
    end
  end

  def edit
    if @student && @student.id == current_student.id
      @course = Course.find_by(id: params[:id])
    else
      redirect_to student_path(current_student), error: 'Sorry, you can\'t view another Users courses.'
    end
  end

  def update
    student = Student.find_by(id: params[:student_id])
    @course = Course.find_by(id: params[:id])
    @course.update(params.require(:course).permit(:course_name))
    redirect_to student_course_path(student, @course)
  end

  def destroy
    @student = Student.find_by(id: params[:student_id])
    @course = Course.find_by(id: params[:id]).destroy
    redirect_to student_path(@student), notice: 'Course was successfully deleted.'
  end

  private

    def course_params
      params.require(:course).permit(:course_name)
    end

    def set_student
      @student = Student.find_by(id: params[:student_id])
    end
end
```

Comment: I stripped a lot of redundant and non-essential information. Conciseness is important when asking questions and it's a balancing act. Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages along with all of "[How To Ask Questions The Smart Way](http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html)".

Comment: Thanks @theTinMan, sorry still getting used to the platform but will try to be more concise in the future!

Answer (score 2):

This line is the source of all the problems:

```
@assignment = Assignment.find_by(id: params[:id])
```

That's a huge mistake. I'd argue that you **never, ever** use the top-level model to fetch records that *must* be secured. The failure state of this code is a user sees everything. This is a problem that can't be fixed by patching over it with an access-control list. Those may not apply correctly every time, someone could find a loophole.

Instead you do this:

```
@assignment = @student.assignments.find_by(id: params[:id])
```

Worst-case scenario is you get a not-found error. It's impossible for someone to bypass this by hacking around with the URL. The failure state here is the record is not found.

If you want your URLs resistant to tampering you'll also want to use *non-sequential identifiers*. On MySQL it's often best to create a secondary column specifically for this purpose, like called `param` or `slug` or `ident`, whatever you prefer, and populate that with something random and harmless like:

```
 before_validation :assign_slug

 def assign_slug
   self.slug ||= SecureRandom.uuid
 end
```

Where that's indexed in your schema for quick retrieval. Where you have a student relationship:

```
 add_index :assignments, [ :student_id, :slug ]
```

Postgres allows using UUID primary keys which might be verbose, but don't allow people to tinker and experiment to expose information. You really can't "guess" a randomized UUID value.

Comment: I'd personally also use `find` instead of `find_by` to let Rails do the error handling. `find` raises an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` when the record is not found, which is handled by Rails by responding with the static 404 page.

Comment: @3limin4t0r I'm a big fan of `find` as well since it allows an exception-based flow, and you can override `find` to look-up by params instead of primary key, matching up with `to_param` for example. Lots of good reasons!

Comment: @tadman thanks a lot, this is a lot of great information so I'm going to start trying to implement. I see you mentioned MySQL, I currently am using sqlite do you think that strategy of setting a slug is still valid? Or would I have to make the transition to MySQL/postgres? Thanks again

Comment: The reason I mention Postgres is because it has fantastic support for UUID primary keys. MySQL and SQLite can do it as well if preferred, but you must store them as text or raw binary, both of which are less than ideal. You can use a random secondary "param" key if UUID isn't a practical option for you. That way you get numerical IDs internally, but opaque, non-enumerable IDs for external use, like in URLs and forms.

Answer (score 1):

This might help you:

In your `CoursesController` and `AssignmentsController`, add a `before_action` in your controllers that will limit student's access.

```
#xxx_controller.rb
class XxxController < ApplicationController
  before_action :require_logged_in
  before_action :set_student
  before_action :check_owner, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Then define the method in your `ApplicationController`:

```
#application_controller.rb
def check_owner
  if @student.blank? || @student.id != current_student.id
    redirect_to student_path(current_student), error: 'Sorry, you can\'t view another Users assignments.'
  end
end
```

Comment: "that will student's access."? "will student's" what? Please edit the answer and clarify that.

Comment: While this test may help solve the problem in this particular case, a better strategy is to avoid the problem in the first place and *always* load using a scope, never against the bare model itself.

Comment: @tadman, when loading through the scope, it means I also have to pass not only the child's ID but also the parent's ID in parameter, right?

Comment: The way I structure my nested controllers is by inheriting from a `Student::BaseController`-type thing where that will have already loaded `@student` as part of a `before_action` handler. This means you can move to the next stage of resolving the `@assignment` based on the `:id` param. For example: `@student = Student.find(params[:student_id] || params[:id])` or something like that.

Comment: A well-designed `BaseController` will do a number of things beyond that, like checking access-control rules (e.g. cancancan permissions), rendering a 404 on a missing ID, etc. Any controller that has a route like `/student/:student_id/...` can inherit from that to benefit.

Answer (score 0):

I guess access restriction is what you are looking for. [CanCanCan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan) will help you to set proper access to pages.

Also please replace `find_by(id: params[:id])` with `find(id)` because it is more readable and more efficient.

Comment: When answering with a recommendation for off-site software please explain why it will solve the problem, and supply an example. It's very difficult to tell if this is spam otherwise.

Answer (score -1):

So you have authentication set up allowing access only to logged in users.

Now you need an authorization process to allow access to certain actions/resources depending on the user id or role.

One popular option is [Pundit](https://github.com/varvet/pundit) and the readme page should get you started.

Comment: When answering with a recommendation for off-site software please explain why it will solve the problem, and supply an example. It's very difficult to tell if this is spam otherwise.